# ListView - its views lose value during scrolling

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a custom ListView . with buttons, TextView etc. Its attached to the fragment not activity. users can interact with ListView where button text and TextView changes.
The problem with list view is that after I scroll up or down all the changes to the views are reset to original state.
How do I keep ListView from redrawing and retain views  values  ?
PS: the only events firing up during scroll are ViewRoot's Touch Event : Touch UP & Touch Down

MenuFragment

```
public ItemsAdapter(Context context, List<MenuListItem> objects, String type, String date, ListView lstView) {
            this.ctx = context;
            this.listView = lstView;
            this.itemsType = type;
            this.items = objects;
            this.date = date;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }


ItemsAdapter itemsAdapter = new ItemsAdapter(getActivity(),itemList,itemType, dateOfMenu,lst);
        lst.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);


void updateList(List<MenuFragment> newItems)
        {

            fragments.addAll(newItems);
            pager.destroyDrawingCache();
            this.notifyDataSetChanged();
            indicator.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: have no idea what code to post. here is the ListView screenshot and some code.

Comment: this happens probably when notifyDataSetChanged is fired, but I cant see why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list adapter connects your data — refered to as the *model* — to your `ListView`.  This model must represent what is to be displayed in the list *at any moment in time*.

Therefore, it's important to capture any user interactions and store them in your model, so that when the `ListView` recreates that list item, it can show all the updates that have happened to that list item.

As users click buttons and edit `TextView`s, you need to update your `MenuItemList` object and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter.